# HDF5 time domain simulation results

Tags: fortran, hdf5

I have been developing a time domain simulation research software in Fortran 2008. In the beginning, I thought it was a good idea to dump everything in binary for speed and then extract what I wanted with another software. I now want to shift to saving directly to HDF5.

During the simulation, at each time-step I get a vector of values (first number is the component and second number is the variable inside that component):

```
t_i Var1-1 Var1-2 ... VarN-M
```

I was thinking to create several groups according to the class of components I have in the simulation and then within each group, another group for each instance that would include the data. Then, during the simulation, at each time step, I will append to each instance the values.

The data is always accessed as time-series, e.g. (t, Var1-1). I am not interested in snapshots of a single time instance.

**My questions:** Should I keep the time in the root and common to all? Is there something to avoid based on past experience (would like to avoid design errors)? I am mainly concerned about the performance. Now I am simply buffering all the vectors generated and dump them at the end in a single write — very high performance.

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. There is nothing version specific in your question.

Comment: I think that your question cannot be answered objectively. It all depends on the nature and size of your data, and on what you want to do with it afterwards. I can say that you should have a look at extendible datasets, there can be quite some overhead if you have tiny datasets.

Comment: As Tom said, we can't tell you the best method. However, I can share "thought experiments" that might help. You define the HDF5 schema, so organize it in a way that is complete and simplifies downstream tasks. The structure you described is fine.(I don't know what you mean by components and instances so can't comment further.) Another method would be to write each result vector in a different dataset (1 each for displacement,velocity, acceleration), and use unique index IDs: 1 for component/instance and 1 for time values. Time and component/instance IDs index to other values in other datasets.

Comment: @kcw78 my issue is that while the data are made available based on the time stamp, they are then accessed for all time. You can think of it as a 2d matrix with the first column being time. The software generates one row every time to be written. However, at the end, I always need to access the data per column.